# How to change given string to regex modified string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Example  strings :

```
 2222 
 333333 
 12345 
 111
 123456789
 12345678
```

Expected result:

```
2@222
333@333
12@345
111
 123@456@789
 12@345@678
```

i.e. `'@'` should be inserted at the 4th,8th,12th etc last position from the end of the string.

I believe this can be done using replace and some other methods in JavaScript.

for validation of output string i have made the regex :

```
^(\d{1,3})(\.\d{3})*?$
```

Comment: How the last two expected results have `.` in it ? can you please explain ?

Comment: The question is updated again?

Comment: Yes..and sorry for that..i think the alphabets we're creating confusion.. i have added more strings too

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression:

```
/(\d)(\d{3})$/
```

this will match and group the first digit `\d` and group the last three `\d{3}` which are then grouped in their own group. Using the matched groups, you can then reference them in your replacement string using `$1` and `$2`.

See example below:

```js
const transform = str => str.replace(/(\d)(\d{3})$/, '$1@$2');

console.log(transform("2222")); // 2@222
console.log(transform("333333")); // 333@333
console.log(transform("12345")); // 12@345
console.log(transform("111")); // 111
```

For larger strings of size *N*, you could use other methods such as `.match()` and reverse the string like so:

```js
const reverse = str => Array.from(str).reverse().join('');
const transform = str => {
  return reverse(reverse(str).match(/(\d{1,3})/g).join('@'));
}

console.log(transform("2222")); // 2@222
console.log(transform("333333")); // 333@333
console.log(transform("12345")); // 12@345
console.log(transform("111")); // 111
console.log(transform("123456789")); // 123@456@789
console.log(transform("12345678")); // 12@345@678
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually the replacement should be at every 4,8,12 and so on if the number is big..eg 123456789 should be 123.456.789 and 12345678 should be 12.345.678

Comment: On side note:- `(\d)(\d{3})$` will be enough

Comment: @CodeManiac oh, I see. Thanks :)

Comment: I have added some other strings too , i saw my question little incomplete..! 

Comment: @user579757 ok, I've updated my answer so it should work with arbitrary string lengths

Answer (score 1):

```js
var test = [
    '111',
    '2222',
    '333333',
    '12345',
    '123456789',
    '1234567890123456'
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.replace(/(?=(?:\B\d{3})+$)/g, '@');
}));
```

Comment: Nice and clean, great!

Answer (score 1):

You could match all the digits. In the replacement insert an `@` after every third digit from the right using a positive lookahead.

```
(?=(?:\B\d{3})+$)
```

- `(?=` Positive lookahead, what is on the right is

  - `(?:\B\d{3})+` Repeat 1+ times not a word boundary and 3 digits
- `$` Assert end of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NkwlRP/1)

```js
const regex = /^\d+$/;
["2222",
  "333333",
  "12345",
  "111",
  "123456789",
  "12345678"
].forEach(s => console.log(
  s.replace(/(?=(?:\B\d{3})+$)/g, "@")
));
```

Comment: hi.. actually alphabets and brackets and  commas are not in the string .. only numbers.... i have used alphabets to just bullet the strings.

Comment: @user579757 I have updated it to match only digits.